# Problem installing wheels containing binary files

Tags: python, pip, cython, python-wheel

I have built some wheels for a project that uses Cython and links to a C library.  Wheels are being built for py35-38 on Linux, MacOSX, and Windows.  The wheels seem to build fine, and test ok.  They are uploaded to PyPI (or in this case, TestPyPI), but I am having inconsistent results installing on various systems.  More specifically, after install, I am having problems importing the package on some systems.  The error is `ImportError: No module named 'primesieve._primesieve'`

On those systems that I have the problems, the compiled binary files do not get installed for some reason.  When I download and inspect the wheel, it contains the binary files as expected.  But for some reason these binary files are not being copied.  Full verbose logging by pip during installation has not revealed anything useful.

This happens even in the system and environment in which the wheels were built.  This seems to indicate that the problem is not due to lack of compatibility or mismatching.

Here is an [example](https://test-files.pythonhosted.org/packages/60/f7/918315f3095a5e9d6f467112a43a953b1253ede7bfab94f85107de9f2a4b/primesieve-2.0.7-cp38-cp38-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl) wheel.

Why are the binary files not being copied during installation?

Any assistance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this was a case of user error.
I was executing a command from the repo directory, the command would then import from the current directory rather than from installed packages, and therefore could not find the compiled files.
See [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7507) for more information.